# Laravel $_Session variable

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a wordpress site and a laravel app located in a child folder.

I'm wanting to share some of the session variables from laravel to the worpdress site. The purpose of the exercise is to display the users current basket on the parent wordpress site.

I am trying to use the standard php $_SESSION along side the laravel session to share the data.. please see below..

laravel code:

```
          public function __construct(){
    if(Session::has("basket")){
        session_start();
        $basket = Session::get("basket");
        $_SESSION['basket_size'] = $basket->size();
        $_SESSION['basket_price'] = $basket->price();
    }
}
```

Wordpress code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="topbasket">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/top-basket.jpg" alt=""> 
    <a href="#">Basket</a> 
    (<?php echo $_SESSION['basket_size'];?> items)
  </div>
```

But don't seem to be getting any joy, the $_SESSION is always empty on the wordpress side, is there any way to overcome this ?

Comment: was the session started inside all files using sessions? Using error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php will tell you if it's set or not.

Comment: I would expect both Laravel and WP to manage the session natively to some degree, and in doing so they may set different values for `session_name`, which would cause them not to utilize each other's session cookie. Take a look at the cookies set by your codebase - there may be two with different names.